# Convert String to Int. Check every field in dictionary and if it says "Int", convert the values of those specific fields in csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

i have a csv file with a header, and two lines with values, like this:
[Csv File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCe0p.png)

And i have a dictionary in python like this:
[Python dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVpQG.png)

All the fields in the csv file are of string type. And i want some of those fields to become Integer. So what i want to do is, to compare the fields in csv to the dictionary, and then check every field from my dictionary, and where it says "Int", i want to convert those fields from the csv to Int. Haven't been able to do it with this current code:

```
try:
    with open('Book1.csv', newline='') as csvFile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
        filedictreader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
        print(type(filedictreader))
        for element in filedictreader:
            for key in element:
                print(key)  
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: " + str(e))
```

Output:

```
<class 'csv.DictReader'>
Site_ID  
Site_Name
Site_Type
Latitude
Longitude
Address
Supplier
Access_Details
Access_Time
Telephone_Number
County
Battery_Hours
Cir_ID
Cir_Type
Cir_Capacity
Cir_Owner
Site_A
Site_B
Cust_Name
Redundancy
Site_A_Node
SiteA_Int
SA_Dish_Height
SA_Dish_Azm
SiteA_size
Site_B_Node
SiteB_Int
SiteB_size
SB_Dish_Height
SB_Dish_Azm
Node_ID
Node_Name
Node_IP
Node_Type
Node_Vendor
Node_Model
Location
Site_ID
Site_Name
Site_Type
Latitude
Longitude
Address
Supplier
Access_Details
Access_Time
Telephone_Number
County
Battery_Hours
Cir_ID
Cir_Type
Cir_Capacity
Cir_Owner
Site_A
Site_B
Cust_Name
Redundancy
Site_A_Node
SiteA_Int
SA_Dish_Height
SA_Dish_Azm
SiteA_size
Site_B_Node
SiteB_Int
SiteB_size
SB_Dish_Height
SB_Dish_Azm
Node_ID
Node_Name
Node_IP
Node_Type
Node_Vendor
Node_Model
Location
```

Comment: The CSV file by definition consists of  strings separated by commas. Once you have read in the rows and converted a value from type `str` to `int`, what do you then want to do with the newly converted values? If you re-write a new CSV file, you will probably end up with what you started with because `int` values will be converted to `str` types for writing out.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment to your question. Here I am showing how you can test each column type and convert the value if it is supposed to be an integer. But as I commented, I don't know what you want to do with it after the conversion. And since you did not provide the `dict1` dictionary in any form that could be copied and pasted (and I was not about type the complete declaration myself, I have only defined one entry for demo purposes).

I have removed the `reader` variable, which is not used and renamed some variables to what for me seems more logical names and to follow the [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for naming varibles.

```py
import csv

dict1 = {
    "Site_Name": "String"
}

try:
    with open('Book1.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
        dictreader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in dictreader:
            for field_name in row:
                if dict1.get(field_name, 'String') == 'Int':
                    # conversion (can throw an exception):
                    row[field_name] = int(row[field_name])            
except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", e)
```